# div adding more scrollbar width/height than it should on iOS

Tags: html, css, ios, iphone, web

I'm making a page with parallax background scrolling based on [Keith Clark's concept](https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/) and I've created a `.background` div with `position: absolute; height: 300%` to act as the background image. The page is a bit more than 3 screen heights and it works fine on PC. On iOS however the div clearly adds a lot of extra space under the footer (which disappears if I set the height to be `100%`). How can I fix this? Thanks!

Here's the code for reference:

```css
/*
*   Josh's Custom CSS Reset
*   https://www.joshwcomeau.com/css/custom-css-reset/
*/

*, *::before, *::after
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}

body
{
    line-height: 1.5;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

img, picture, video, canvas, svg
{
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}

input, button, textarea, select
{
    font: inherit;
}

/*
*   Website Styles
*/

:root
{
    --clr-text: #DBDBDB;
    --clr-nav: #242424;

    --fw-light: 300;
    --fw-regular: 400;
    --fw-bold: 700;

    --fs-s: 1rem;
    --fs-m: 1.0625rem;
    --fs-l: 1.1875rem;

    --ff-primary: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

/*
* Utility Classes
*/

.fw-light
{
    font-weight: var(--fw-light);
}

.fw-regular
{
    font-weight: var(--fw-regular);
}

.fw-bold
{
    font-weight: var(--fw-bold);
}

.fs-s
{
    font-size: var(--fs-s);
}

.fs-m
{
    font-size: var(--fs-m);
}

.fs-l
{
    font-size: var(--fs-l);
}

/*
* General Styling
*/

html
{
    overflow: hidden;
}

body
{
    font-weight: var(--fw-light);
    font-size: var(--fs-s);
    font-family: var(--ff-primary);
    color: var(--clr-text);

    background-color: black;

    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    perspective: 1px;
    perspective-origin: top;

    /*
    background-image: url("images/bg1.png");
    background-position: center;
    */
}

.background
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300%; /* TODO: make 350vh without adding extra space to page */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: translateZ(-2px) scale(3.01);
    transform-origin: top;
    background-image: url("https://i.redd.it/1ugxymchkgh51.jpg"); /* "images/bg1.png" */
    background-position: top;
    background-size: cover;
}

section
{
    height: 100vh;
}

.container
{
    width: 80%;
    margin-inline: auto;
}

.even-columns
{
    display: grid;
    gap: 1rem;
}

@media(min-width: 50em)
{
    .even-columns
    {
        grid-auto-flow: column;
        grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="background"></div>

    <header class="primary-header">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.svg" alt="logo"></a>
            <nav class="primary-navigation">
                <ul role="list" class="nav-list">
                    <li><a href="#">Streams</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Genre Guide</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <main>
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="even-columns">
                    <div>
                        <h1 class="fw-bold fs-l">About Streams</h1>
                        <p>
                            Where to join streams + perhaps some info about them?
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            Lorem ipsum
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h1 class="fw-bold fs-l">Discord!</h1>
                        <p>Info about Discord + invitation</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <div>
                    <h1 class="fw-bold fs-l">About Music</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div>
                <ul role="list" aria-label="Social links">
                    <li><a aria-label="discord" href="#"><img src="images/discord.svg" alt="discord logo">Discord</a></li>
                    <li><a aria-label="cytube" href="#"><img src="images/cytube.svg" alt="cytube logo">Cytube</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#">Feedback</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's how the issue looks:
[image: issue]

And there's a evn more space below what's already shown in the iOS image

Comment: did you try `300vh` instead of `300%` ??

Comment: @KunalTanwar yup, same result